# MySQL PDO UPDATE only doesnt work when used in class

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I struggle a lot with UPDATE query when used in class. Other queries like SELECT, ALTER work just fine. Query itsef works well in phpmyadmin and if PDO is defined in procedural way (but exactly the same as in class) the very same query works. Struggling with it for days and now I simply give up hence my question here. Error reporting is on

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Also error reporting is set as attribute upon creating an object but no errors thrown for UPDATE.

Environment is localhost on Linux Mint 17.3. Working code (but not for UPDATE):

```
class MySQLDatabase {
    private $PDO;
    private $error;

    private $host = _DB_SERVER_;
    private $dbname = _DB_NAME_;
    private $user = _DB_USER_;
    private $passwd = _DB_PASSWD_;

    private $stmt;  

    public function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->PDO = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbname.';charset=utf8', ''.$this->user.'', ''.$this->passwd.'');
            $this->PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function update_records(){

        $query = 'UPDATE ps_2orders
                SET
                    rozliczone = 1
                WHERE
                    id_order = 1535';

        $this->query($query);
        $this->execute();
    }
    public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($query);
    }
    public function execute() {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }
```

Now working code:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='._DB_SERVER_.';dbname='._DB_NAME_.';charset=utf8', ''._DB_USER_.'', ''._DB_PASSWD_.'');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit('Database connection error.');
}

$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ps_2orders
                SET
                    rozliczone = 1
                WHERE
                    id_order = 1535");
    $query->execute();
```

What I tried so far: mostly adapting the query but obviously its not query causing the problem. It must have something to do with with object.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also if I pass incorrect column name it throws an error that column doesnt exist so it connects to database just fine but doesnt update anything

Comment: Your code looks okay. Are you trying with $obj = new MySQLDatabase(); then $obj->update_records()?

Comment: Found the problem (I always seem to find solution after posting on forum it happened to me like 10 times lol). Problem was: somewhere in the php script in instantiate class to $database = new MySQLDatabase(); than after if(isset($_GET['generate'])){ $database->query($query); $database->execute();} (and it is not working code) but when I inside if(isset($_GET['generate'])){ $database = new MySQLDatabase(); and than $database->query($query); $database->execute();} it works and results get updated in db. So my question is why do I have to instantiate again to get UPDATE to actually update?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'UPDATE ps_2orders SET rozliczone=:rozliczone WHERE id_order = :id_order';
$stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':rozliczone' => 1, ':id_order' => 1535));
```

This will work.
because you have made pdo object with :

```
$this->PDO = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbname.';charset=utf8', ''.$this->user.'', ''.$this->passwd.'');
$this->PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

so you have to use by `$this->PDO->pdoFunctions`.

Comment: my function: public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($query);
    } does it for me right? so $this->query($query) should work just fine. I think you are trying to say to use $this->PDO->prepare($query);
$this->PDO->execute(); instead $this->PDO->query($query);
$this->PDO->execute();?

Comment: yes any pdo functions can be use with`$thjis->PDO` you might use `$this->PDO->prepare($query);$this->PDO->execute();` for the good practice.

Comment: public function update_records(){
   
   $query = 'UPDATE ps_2orders
     SET
      rozliczone = 1
     WHERE
      id_order = 1535';
  
  $this->PDO->query($query);
  $this->PDO->execute();
 } gives me error Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in /var/www/html/rozne/rozliczenia/classes/MySQLDatabase.php on line 158 (which is $this->PDO->execute();) so tried $this->execute(); no error but record didnt get updated

Comment: $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(); doesnt update anything in db but no error either

Comment: Found the problem (I always seem to find solution after posting on forum it happened to me like 10 times lol). Problem was: somewhere in the php script in instantiate class to $database = new MySQLDatabase(); than after  if(isset($_GET['generate'])){ $database->query($query); $database->execute();} (and it is not working code) but when I inside if(isset($_GET['generate'])){ $database = new MySQLDatabase(); and than $database->query($query); $database->execute();} it works and results get updated in db. So my question is why do I have to instantiate again to get UPDATE to actually update?